# Annotation 'incompatible types' compiler error

Tags: java, annotations

Out of curiousity: I have followind SSCCE

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

    @Path("/")
       public class T {

        void a() {

            Path p = getClass().getAnnotation(Path.class); //1

            Class z = getClass();
            p = z.getAnnotation(Path.class); //2
        }
}
```

Compiler gives following error message:

```
T.java:12: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.annotation.Annotation
required: javax.ws.rs.Path
        p = z.getAnnotation(Path.class); 
Note: T.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
```

What is difference of line //1 and //2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an odd feature of raw types. When you use generic type (`Class<T>`) as a raw type (`Class`), its members are treated as their erasures.

[JLS §4.8 Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html#4.8):

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.8, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

Effectively, use of raw type disables all generic-related stuff in declarations of its members.

In your case method of `Class<T>` declared as

```
public <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(Class<A> annotationClass)
```

turns into its erasure

```
public Annotation getAnnotation(Class annotationClass)
```

and you get an error caused by assignment of `Annotation` to `Path`.

In order to prevent it you need to use generic type in its parameterized form. If you don't care about actual value of `T` in `Class<T>`, use wildcard:

```
void b(Class<?> z) {
    Path p = z.getAnnotation(Path.class); 
}
```